# How can I compare two collections using == with AssertJ?

Tags: java, insertion-sort, assertj, stability

I just implemented my own [Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) and trying to verify functionalities including [stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).

For a given list of unsorted elements, I'm trying to verify my code against [Collections#sort(List)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) method.

```java
List<E> unsorted = ...; // <E extends Comparable<? super E>>

List<E> sorted1 = new ArrayList<>(unsorted);
Collections.sort(sorted1);

List<E> sorted2 = new ArrayList<>(unsorted);
MyInsertionSort.sort(sorted2);
```

I found [AbstractIterableAssert#containsExactlyElementsOf](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsExactlyElementsOf(java.lang.Iterable)) method.

```java
        assertThat(sorted2)
                .isSorted()
                .isSortedAccordingTo(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                .containsExactlyElementsOf(sorted1)
        ;
```

I ended up while tracing the method to the point calling `Comparator#compare`.

Is the `containsExactlyElementsOf` method covers the stability?

Or is there any other method should I add for the `stability`?

### Supplement

Let us say we have following unsorted list. (I used the `mapToObj` for a testing purpuse.)

```java
List<Integer> unsorted = IntStream.of(2, 0, 0, 3, 1)
        .mapToObj(Integer::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I produced a base result.

```java
// might be stable
List<Integer> sorted1 = Collections.sort(new ArrayList<>(unsorted));
```

And produced my result.

```java
// should be stable
List<Integer> sorted2 = MyInsertionSort.sort(new ArrayList<>(unsorted));
```

Both lists might be sorted and it's easy to be asserted as described above.

Now say the logic is not well and the stability is broken.

```java
Collections.swap(sorted2, 0, 1); // swap first two zeros from 0, 0, 1, 2, 3
```

How can I assert, which should fails, that not all elements in `sorted2` are **same** with each elements of `sorted1`?

Without following simple loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < sorted2.size(); i++) {
    assertThat(sorted2.get(i))
            .isSameAs(sorted1.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Issued on https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2365

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I can confirm/find any way.

I just tried following simple loop.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < sorted2.size(); i++) {
    assertThat(sorted2.get(i))
            .isSameAs(sorted1.get(i));
}
```

As issued and answered on https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2365#issuecomment-939681420

Anyone can do this.

```java
 assertThat(sorted2)
                .isSorted()
                .isSortedAccordingTo(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                .usingElementComparator((o1, o2) -> o1 == o2 ? 0 : -1)
                .containsExactlyElementsOf(sorted1) // should fail and it does
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasSameElementsAs()` method from AssertJ.
This method ignores the duplicates and validates both has same elements
`assertThat(firstCollection).hasSameElementsAs(secondCollection);`
It is advised to validate the size first when we go for this method.

If you dont worry about the order then we can use `containsExactlyInAnyOrder()`.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/assertj-and-collections-introduction this link might help you

Comment: I'm afraid the [`hasSameElementsAs`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.21.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#hasSameElementsAs(java.lang.Iterable)) also calls `comparator#compare`.